# What's the meaning of thinking they not?

Tags: meaning-in-context, idioms

South African fast bowler Dale Steyn  made a statement on Twitter recently:

***"Apologies to Virat and a billion people for thinking they not"***

What is he apologising for? What's the meaning of the phrase "thinking they not"?

Comment: Poor grammar, typo, or possibly even regional slang. Take your pick. Perhaps its a sarcastic response to 'Virat and billions'... much like "told you so!" is when pointing out someone's error. The fact it's been deleted alludes to it being a regrettable statment.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a typo (supported by the fact that I can't find the tweet anymore so it might have been deleted) or an unfinished sentence. "thinking they not" does not make any sense without a lot of added words.

Comment: Maybe this could lead you to the Twitter post:Dale Steyn (@DaleSteyn62) Tweeted: @NeilManthorp Apologies to Virat and a billion people for thinking they not https://twitter.com/DaleSteyn62/status/1161290269746237441?s=17

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't looking for replies. Still stand by my statement though, the tweet does not make sense.